# In nft scope ,how to use python translate the lower contract_address to the standard display

Tags: python, smartcontracts, nft

i  want to follow  the ECR-721 rule  to standardize the display of all the contract_addresses that are made up with the low character

i d  like to change `0xa66cc78067fd1e6aa3eec4ccdff88d81527f92c1` into `0xA66CC78067fd1E6Aa3eEC4CcdFF88D81527F92c1`
Have any one know the regular and true rule